# How to create a Node.js service that downloads contents of a page when requested and return the results?

Tags: node.js, request

How can I create a Node.js service that downloads contents of a page when requested and return the results? Consider the following Express app.js:

```
app.get('/service/:url', (req, res) => res.send(downloadPage(req.params.url)));

function getPage(address) {
    const request = require('request')

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(address, (error, response, body) => {
         if (error) reject(error);
         if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
             reject('Invalid status code <' + response.statusCode + '>');
         }
         resolve(body);
      });
   });
}

async function sendRequest(address) {
    try {
        return await getPage(address)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return 'ERROR';
    }
}

function downloadPage(address){
    return `enter code here`sendRequest(address)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
app.get('/service/:url', (req, res) => downloadPage(req.params.url).then(function (result){
    res.send(result)
}).catch(err => res.send(err)));
```